# Using JQuery to create hyperlink found in a paragraph

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

How can you use JQuery to find URLs within some text and automatically convert them into an actual hyperlink?

Example text,

> var TextMemo = "This is some random
> paragraph text, but i mention a link to a
> website here. [www.stackoverflow.com](http://www.stackoverflow.com)
> and another one here this time with
> http (http://www.google.co.uk)"

Is this a simple task?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it won't be as simple as replacing text in a single string because a typical paragraph will be made up of one or more text and element nodes which need to be traversed properly in order to effectively wrap the desired piece of text. You shouldn't be getting the text with something like innerText/textContent or innerHTML.

Try this:

```
var para = jQuery('#my-para')[0];

findMatchAndReplace(
    para,
    /\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i,
    '<a href="$&">$&</a>'
);
```

Using this function:

```
function findMatchAndReplace(node, regex, replacement) {

    var parent,
        temp = document.createElement('div'),
        next;

    if (node.nodeType === 3) {

        parent = node.parentNode;

        temp.innerHTML = node.data.replace(regex, replacement);

        while (temp.firstChild)
            parent.insertBefore(temp.firstChild, node);

        parent.removeChild(node);

    } else if (node.nodeType === 1) {

        if (node = node.firstChild) do {
            next = node.nextSibling;
            findMatchAndReplace(node, regex, replacement);
        } while (node = next);

    }

}
```